# have two apps in angular2 like main components

Tags: angular

Is cpossible to have two apps in html for angular 2? or everything must be inside in a main app or component ?

```
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
<my-app2>Loading...</my-app2>
</body>
```

if in angular2 everything separated component i think that mus be possible.. or really myapp main is not real component; or something link big container master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular won't stop you from calling `bootstrap` twice with two different apps (for example: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6j9WRSuUb72JIg1VBgko?p=preview)). I've never seen anyone suggest you do this, however, so I don't know if there are any nasty consequences down the road.

Comment: thanks; maybe is a not good practice ? i try to integrate isolate component to my backend php that is not full angular app